# Error in Intellij IDEA when I try to set up Google Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use Google Cloud as Repository of my code in Intellij IDEA.
I downloaded the Google Cloud plugin but when I browse thru projects i got this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to this open issue in [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2568): they were using a no longer working service URL for the API calls to fetch the list of cloud source repositories. A fix is going in now and will make it on the next release (likely around the last week of this month).

In the meantime we suggest checking out the repository via the [command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/source/repos/list). Once the fix is in, you could grab the [nightly](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij#installation) release which will contain the fix.

Comment: thx (even if I'don't understand the downvotes to my question)